# Title of a book with a girl found under a tree with eyes sewn shut

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a pretty interesting book a couple months ago, and it started with a girl being found under the roots of a tree where she had been for years with her eyes sewed shut. Basically what happened was that there were 4 or 5 people born with elemental magic or something, and there was another girl who could control water. In the version I read back then, there was a picture of a really old house of the cover and tree branches. I think that's all I remember.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Fiendish*, by Brenna Yovanoff**

[image: Cover of "Fiendish" by Brenna Yovanoff. The cover shows a gray multi-story house with leafless trees surrounding it. Roots spread out from the bottom of the house towards the reader. The background shows a stormy, cloudy scene.]

> Clementine DeVore spent ten years trapped in a cellar, pinned down by willow roots, silenced and forgotten.
>
> Now she’s out and determined to uncover who put her in that cellar and why.
>
> When Clementine was a child, dangerous and inexplicable things started happening in New South Bend. The townsfolk blamed the fiendish people out in the Willows and burned their homes to the ground. But magic kept Clementine alive, walled up in the cellar for ten years, until a boy named Fisher sets her free. Back in the world, Clementine sets out to discover what happened all those years ago. But the truth gets muddled in her dangerous attraction to Fisher, the politics of New South Bend, and the Hollow, a fickle and terrifying place that seems increasingly temperamental ever since Clementine reemerged.
> <sub>-[Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18667948-fiendish)</sub>

And a [comment on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/993591541?book_show_action=true&from_review_page=1) makes it clear that the eyes of the girl were sewn shut:

> I'm not a huge fan of creepy, but I was in the mood for it. I wanted something that was going to give me that scared feeling, make me feel a tickle on the back of my neck in the dark, maybe make me wonder about the what ifs. Fiendish started off with such great promise, a girl locked in a cellar for ten years, tangled in roots, eyes sewed shut, and no one seems to remember her when she emerges into the light. I was so sure I'd made a good choice.